# Is it possible to builk insert ignore / insert or update with eloquent or query builder in Laravel 5.8? Without looping each record?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

Im generating a lot of data that i would like to store in DB, sometime part of data that i would store already exists in DB. How can i insert bulk amount of records without looping them all?

Answer (score 1):

I am walking for this problem before, I have like 3000k of the row to insert in MySQL so the only reasonable way that I can resolve this problem was with:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DB::statement('Your raw SQL query here')`